# Carry a drone during a Dubai/Seychelles trip

Tags: dubai, drones, seychelles

Next month I will travel from Italy to Seychelles for my honeymoon and I wish to carry my drone (a DJI Mavic PRO) with me. I'm aware that flying a drone without a license is illegal in Dubai but since I will stay there for 3 days I want to be sure if I can just carry it in my luggage **without** actually flying it or if I risk to have it taken by customs/police.

Comment: Also be sure to check airline restrictions on lithium batteries.

Comment: Make sure the miss does not mind you spending time with the drone rather than her ;)

Comment: @Itai you're right :) i'll double check on that

Comment: did you bring your drone in your carry-on?

Comment: @Samuel.Levallois yes I did. I bought a separate pouch specifically for batteries that's supposed to be fire retardant, even though neither Emirates nor Air Seychelles required that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While drones are permitted in the Seychelles, you would first want to check whether the airline carrier(s) allow it in your checked baggage, and for all of your flights, not just the Dubai stopover.

As this regulation is under the purview of the UAE General Civil Aviation Authority (DCA), and you will arrive and depart through its airport, you may come under scrutiny. Although you have no plans to fly it in the UAE, the decision is so recent, it would be best to ask the [Dubai Civil Aviation Authority](https://www.dcaa.gov.ae/SitePages/en/home.aspx). Its [brochure on RPAS/drones](https://www.dcaa.gov.ae/Files/DCAAFLYERA6V4.pdf) has these contacts:

Salim Alsuwaidi
salim.alsuwaidi@dcaa.gov.ae
+971 4 5042781

Michael Rudolph
michael.rudolph@dcaa.gov.ae
+971 4 5042769

Ellen Almeida
ellen.almeida@dcaa.gov.ae
+971 4 5042768

Answer (score 3):

Back from the trip :) No problems at all with the drone. I passed through both countries customs without any issues at all. Didn't fly it in Dubai though due to lacking a state license).
Just an advice for Seychelles, beware that Air Seychelles planes fly at relatively low altitudes and there are a couple helicopters flying too so you better keep an eye on those while operating a drone to avoid collisions.